# JSON without array wrapper on lower levels

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

All I try to get is a simple SQL statement to build:

```
 {"status":{"code":404,"message":"Not found"},"otherthing":20}
```

If I set as :

```
DECLARE @ReturnJSON nvarchar(max)

SET @ReturnJSON = (
    SELECT ( 
        SELECT 404 as [code]
              ,'Not found' as [message] 
               FOR JSON PATH ) as [status]
       , 20 as [otherthing]
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) ;

SELECT @ReturnJSON
```

I get the second level under an array wrapper, like this:

```
{"status":[{"code":404,"message":"Not found"}],"otherthing":20}
```

But if I add the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` on the second level...

```
DECLARE @ReturnJSON nvarchar(max)

SET @ReturnJSON = (
    SELECT ( 
        SELECT 404 as [code]
              ,'Not found' as [message] 
               FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER ) as [status]
       , 20 as [otherthing]
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) ;

SELECT @ReturnJSON
```

something funny happens:

```
{"status":"{\"code\":404,\"message\":\"Not found\"}","otherthing":20}
```

I am missing something, I know, sure, but I can not for-see

Comment: You could try to wrap the query in JSON_QUERY. IMHO these backslashes in your JSON string are escaping the double quotes inside your string. Your JSON is a valid.

Comment: @Matheno, I believe this is not my case, 

first JSON is what I try to obtain, second and third all what I achieve,

**How is possible to achieve that first JSON**

Answer (score 26):

I think that Matheno (in the comments) is right: apparently the problem is that `FOR JSON` escapes your text. To prevent this unwanted escaping of inner JSON you could wrap it with `JSON_QUERY()`:

```
DECLARE @ReturnJSON nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @innerJSON nvarchar(max)

set @innerJSON =(        SELECT 404 as [code]
              ,'Not found' as [message] 
               FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER )

SET @ReturnJSON = (
    SELECT ( 
        JSON_QUERY(@innerJSON)
               ) as [status]
       , 20 as [otherthing]
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) ;

SELECT @ReturnJSON
```

This outputs:

```
{"status":{"code":404,"message":"Not found"},"otherthing":20}
```

Comment: Relevant reading [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148399/142517) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/21/without_array_wrapper-new-important-change-in-for-json/). From the second link: "Note one important thing – WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER will not generate valid JSON text. If you try to put FOR JSON WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER as column expression, it will be treated as a plain text..."

Comment: So long as there is only one row, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER indeed generates valid JSON.

Answer (score 8):

It's not exact answer to your question, but I hope it will give solution to your problem.

You can construct expected output without nested query, just define hierarchy using property names, like this:

```
DECLARE @ReturnJSON nvarchar(max)

SET @ReturnJSON = (
    SELECT 
        404 as [status.code]
        ,'Not found' as [status.message]
        , 20 as [otherthing]
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) ;

SELECT @ReturnJSON
```

Comment: This is an official way to achieve the expected result. See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15.
If you use WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER the result is valid JSON only if there is only one dataset in the result. I guess Microsoft decided to treat it as string just in case. Thats for the reason of the Problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the extra variables, you can inline the innerJson like this:

```
DECLARE @ReturnJSON AS NVARCHAR(max);

SET @ReturnJSON = (SELECT JSON_QUERY((SELECT [code], [message] FOR JSON PATH)) AS [Status] 
FROM (VALUES(404, 'Non found', 20)) AS src([code], [message], [otherthing])
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SELECT @ReturnJSON
```

Same output as Andrea

```
{"Status":[{"code":404,"message":"Non found"}]}
```