# SQL Server JSON QUERY

Tags: sql-server

I have to write a query to retrieve data in single json object format.

I have mixed columns. few of them are JSON and few of them are numerical values.  While retrieving data i should convert each row to single JSON object. My query is giving me single object but it is giving me results with \\ slashes. Can someone help me in reformatting the below query which should exclude the slashes while formatting each row into single JSON object.

```
(select 
(select 
p.personReferenceNumber as personReferenceNumber,
personIdentity as personIdentity,
isnull([name],'')  as [name],
p.gender as gender,
isnull(p.birthDateHijri,'') as birthDateHijri,
isnull(p.birthDateGregorian,'') as birthDateGregorian,
isnull(p.liveStatus,'') as liveStatus,
isnull(p.nationality,'') as nationality,
isnull(p.specific,'') as specific,
isnull(p.isDeleted,'') as isDeleted,
isnull(p.sessionId,'') as sessionId,
isnull(p.insertedBy,'') as insertedBy,
isnull(p.insertedTimeStamp,'') as insertedTimeStamp,
isnull(p.updatedBy,'') as updatedBy,
isnull(p.updatedTimestamp,'') as updatedTimestamp
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS person
from person p)
```

Output:

```
{\"messageId\":\"f616dbd3-1352-404b-939e-5b12f90b57fe\",
 \"transactionRowId\":594834948322275328,
 \"personId\":\"bebox13\",
 \"idType\":2,\"issueDateHijri\":14400203,
 \"issueDateGregorian\":\"2019-04-12T03:00:00\",
 \"expiryDateHijri\":14400104,
 \"expiryDateGregorian\":\"2019-04-12T03:00:00\",
 \"issuePlace\":[\"Update\",
 \"Update\"]}",
"name":
"{\\\"messageId\\\":\\\"f616dbd3-1352-404b-939e-5b12f90b57fe\\\",
  \\\"transactionRowId\\\":594834948322275328,
  \\\"firstName\\\":[\\\"Update\\\",\\\"Update\\\"],\\\"secondName\\\":[\\\"Update\\\",\\\"Update\\\"],\\\"thirdName\\\":[\\\"Update\\\",\\\"Update\\\"],\\\"familyName\\\":[\\\"Update\\\",\\\"Update\\\"]}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON without array wrapper on lower levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957850/json-without-array-wrapper-on-lower-levels)

Comment: The fields in your output don't match those in your query. Also your outer `SELECT` is returning the result of your `FOR JSON`.

Comment: @PeterSmith: JSON_QUERY(columName) solves my problem. Thanks.