# SQL - How to store JSON_QUERY output to variable

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have this query in which I'm trying to store the query output into `@json` variable but getting syntax error

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @json = (JSON_QUERY((SELECT 
                                'Ball' AS title, 
                                'Blue' AS color, 
                                (SELECT 
                                     '1' AS Opt1, 
                                     '2' AS Opt2 
                                 FOR JSON PATH) AS Options
                            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Product
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;)

SELECT @json
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could this be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957850/json-without-array-wrapper-on-lower-levels

Comment: Put SELECT in front of JSON_QUERY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following VBokšić's link I made this query as answer:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json = (SELECT (JSON_QUERY((
    SELECT 'Ball' AS title, 
           'Blue' AS color, (
                SELECT '1' AS Opt1, 
                       '2' AS Opt2 
                FOR JSON PATH
           ) AS Options
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ))) AS product
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SELECT @json
```

Output:

```
{"product":{"title":"Ball","color":"Blue","Options":[{"Opt1":"1","Opt2":"2"}]}}
```

Comment: And I will give you an up vote for your effort :) I am happy that it helped.