# Return results in custom JSON format

Tags: sql-server

I have this sample query:

```
SELECT'12345' as param1, 'abcdef' as param2  for json path, root('values');
```

that returns a json like:

```
 {"values":**[**{"param1":"12345","param2":"abcdef"}**]**}
```

but it would be very helpful to have a result (without array) like:

```
 {"values":{"param1":"12345","param2":"abcdef"}}
```

Is there an elegant solution for this? I would avoid a second select that returns the [0] element.

Comment: I think this will help you out [JSON without array wrapper on lower levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957850/json-without-array-wrapper-on-lower-levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with the following statement, using `FOR JSON PATH` and dot-separated column names:

Statement:

```
SELECT
   '12345' AS 'values.param1', 
   'abcdef' AS 'values.param2'  
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{"values":{"param1":"12345","param2":"abcdef"}}
```